# C# - CEFSharp remove BrowserSubProcess.exe dependency

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Is it possible to remove the dependency upon CEFSharp and/or just put it's code inside the main application and run from there instead?

Why is this needed?
I need to obfuscate my application and the obfuscation method being used can't use 2 .exe's - and it requires all dependencies to be selected, and since the SubProcess.exe is a dependency, I'm not able to obfuscate.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/57/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Program.cs#L27

Comment: I'll also point out that the browser subprocess is a runtime dependency, not a compile time one, long as the browser can access it when running it doesn't need to be present when compiling or obfuscating.

Answer (score 0):

Not with how CEFSharp was designed.  CEF uses multiple processes for different tasks.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Files_required

```
 Filename     Always required     Description   Release
 CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe   Yes   Browser subprocess executable   all
 CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll    Yes Browser subprocess stuff    all
 ...
```

The link above to the CEFSharp wiki also has links to the latest readme (which should be in the CEFSharp package you downloaded) and to a dependency checker.

If you were using the base CEF3 and unmanaged C++ you'd still need to distribute all the chromium and CEF3 DLLs but you could use your single EXE for both the main and child processes.

Comment: So theres no way to per say embed the .exe into the main .exe without Fody

Comment: The issue is that your app needs to run, then it needs to spawn 2 or more helper processes that behave differently.  The main process is the "browser" process that handles UI and the cookie store.  One helper process handles HTML parsing and the JavaScript engine.  I'm not familiar with Fody beyond a quick Google so I can't say whether it would let you add the sub-process EXE into your main one.